# darkened window and cannot control application, then stuck window

Tags: 14.04

I'm new to ubuntu 14.04.
Sometimes my window gets darkened, and I can't initiate any movement on the darkened page.

For example, I can't do anything on this application, but still can initiate other movement like terminal, firebox,etc.

[darkened window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRIM1.png)

Five minutes later, my window is fully stuck. cannot do anything.

[stuck window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OOmj.png)

Five minutes later again, it's recovered from stuck window(but darkened application still goes on).....

May you help get me know why this happened and how to fix it?
Thanks!

I made ubuntu hibernated last night, is't a reason?